# I'm trying to use the Facebook API to get lead information on an ad, but I keep getting an error message

Tags: python, facebook-graph-api, facebook-python-business-sdk

So, I'm trying to use Python and the Facebook API to get the lead info for an ad. I'm following the instructions under Bulk Read on this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/guides/lead-ads/retrieving. And my code looks like this:

```
from facebook_business.adobjects.ad import Ad
from facebook_business.adobjects.lead import Lead
from facebook_business.api import FacebookAdsApi
import os

access_token = os.getenv('FB_ACCESS_TOKEN')
app_secret = os.getenv('FB_APP_SECRET')
app_id = os.getenv('FB_APP_ID')
id = '23850504679460681'
FacebookAdsApi.init(access_token=access_token)

fields = [
]
params = {
}
print(Ad(id).get_leads(
  fields=fields,
  params=params,
  ))
```

When I run this, I get this error message:

```
C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\python_code\Facebook API>python leadget.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\Desktop\python_code\Facebook API\leadget.py", line 16, in <module>
    print(Ad(id).get_leads(
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook_business\adobjects\ad.py", line 622, in get_leads
    return request.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook_business\api.py", line 677, in execute
    cursor.load_next_page()
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook_business\api.py", line 841, in load_next_page
    response_obj = self._api.call(
  File "C:\Users\Joseph\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\facebook_business\api.py", line 350, in call
    raise fb_response.error()
facebook_business.exceptions.FacebookRequestError:

  Message: Call was not successful
  Method:  GET
  Path:    https://graph.facebook.com/v13.0/23850504679460681/leads
  Params:  {'summary': 'true'}

  Status:  400
  Response:
    {
      "error": {
        "message": "(#100) Requires pages_manage_ads or leads_retrieval permission to manage the object",
        "type": "OAuthException",
        "code": 100,
        "fbtrace_id": "ALhUN1djYRl_0HTb4RHZuHF"
      }
    }
```

I've checked, and both I and the app have those permissions. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hope it's not too late for you but it seems to need more permissions to get leads information.
you can do this in your facebook developer application

[image: like this]